# How to upload a encrypted data bag using knife

Tags: knife, databags

Hi am trying to create a chef server copying all files from an existing chef server. So when copied everything and ran a recipe it's getting error as data bag is encrypted. 
So, I downloaded keytab from an encrypted data bag on old chef server. 
    Knife vault download keys sri_keytab sri.keytab 
Now I want to upload the data bag to my new chef server. I heard it's only possible in the case when we decrypt a data bag using vault and the keytab downloaded and then upload it as an encrypted one.
But I don't know how
So could anyone help me please......

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

- Decrypt a data bag from the old server
- create a json file with the decrypted data
- create a vault from the new json file to the new server

you can use this as reference [chef-vault](https://blog.chef.io/2016/01/21/chef-vault-what-is-it-and-what-can-it-do-for-you/)